# Excel's VBA ActiveWorkbook is "Nothing" when "Enable Editing" from ProtectedView

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro which is called from a spreadsheet function (user defined function, UDF). When the spreadsheet is downloaded from the internet and the user has set "Trust Center" settings accordingly, the spreadsheet will open in so the called "Protected View". The function will not be called. A button "Enable Editing" is shown.
If the button is pressed, the spreadsheet is "trusted" and reopened normally, starting calculation, and hence calling the user defined function.

However, in that VBA function the value of `Application.ActiveWorkbook` is `Nothing`. This can be verified in the debugger.

Since I just need to read some properties (like path name) of the spreadsheet, I could alternatively inspect the availability of `Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow` which should reference to the protected version of the workbook. In the debugger, this object can be inspected. However, running in release (without debug) the value of `Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow` is also `Nothing`.

Both behaviors - especially the first one - appears to be a bug present in Excel 2010 and 2013 (see also [a post at the MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18d7071b-18ec-4443-ad8c-872bc59fcc8a/activeworkbook-is-nothing-after-enable-editing-is-clicked-for-excel-2010-protected-view?forum=isvvba) ).

> **Question**: Is there a way to get hold of properties of the *active workbook* after it has been enabled for editing?

PS: As a follow up to the nice observation of Siddharth Rout, that "ThisWorkbook" might work: In my case, the macro is not part of the Workbook being openend. The UDF is defined in an XLA. Hence, ThisWorkbook would reference the XLA. I do need to get the ActiveWorkbook (= the workbook calling the UDF) instead of ThisWorkbook (= the workbook running the UDF).

**IMPORTANT REQUIREMENT:**

1. My function is called as a user defined function, i.e., execution order is determined by Excel updating the cell.
2. The function is not part of the workbook being opened. It is part of an XLA.
3. I cannot add any code to the workbook which is opened.

Comment: Did the workbook opened in the browser or from the Excel application? I only encountered this when it opens in the browser. Try this experiment. Open the URL within Excel.

Comment: The workbook is part of a ZIP file. The zip file is downloaded to a Window 7 host. The zip file is extracted to a directory. Windows 7 will then "mark" the file as being obtained from an internet source and Excel 2013 will open the XLS file in "protected view". This is the Windows 7/Excel default behavior. And most "users" will download and open it that way... (it's not me, it's my user who is opening the file).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Summary:** *The problem can be replicated and there are some possible workarounds. The most promising one - resulting from a chat - is to use `ActiveWindow.Parent` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`.*

---

I was able to replicate the problem.

I tried

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Application.ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing = " & _
    CStr(Application.ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing)
End Sub
```

And I got `True`

However, then I tried this and it gave me `False`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Application.ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing = " & _
    CStr(Application.ThisWorkbook Is Nothing)
End Sub
```

**Now answering your question...**

> Question: Is there a way to get hold of properties of the workbook after it has been enabled for editing?

Yes. Use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`

**Followup From Comments**

Once the workbook completely loads after you exit the `Protected Mode`, you would be able to access the `ActiveWorkbook` object. To test this, put this code in the protected file.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    MsgBox "Application.ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing = " & _
    CStr(Application.ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing)
End Sub
```

You will notice that you get a `False`

So once your workbook loads, your add-in can use `ActiveWorkbook` to interact with the opened file.

Here is another test

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Path
End Sub
```

This is what I got the moment, I exit the `Protected Mode`

[image]

**FOLLOWUP FROM CHAT**

Using `ActiveWindow.Parent.Path` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Path` would solve the problem.

Comment: Interesting. However, this is not a solution to my problem: The macro is not in the workbook itself. It is in an XLA. ThisWorkbook given the workbook where the macro resides in. I do want the active workbook.

Comment: But then you should be able to access the workbook from XLA once it is opened. I put the above code `CStr(Application.ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing)` in the `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()` and it gave me `False` :)

Comment: This is interesting too. Did I got this right: You suggest to put Workbook_Activate in the XLA (where the Macro resides)? Isn't it that this will be called only once for the XLA, namely when it is activated. But not again, when (another) protected sheet has made "Enable editing"? (Note that the workbook which is enabled does not contain any macros at all - hence an Workbook_Activate in this sheet would be not option.

Comment: No I didn't mean that you had to insert the Workbook_Activate` either in the workbook or the Add-In. What I was trying to demonstrate with `Workbook_Activate` is that the `ActiveWorkbook` was available to you once the workbook completed loaded. So your add-in shouldn't find any difficulty in using `ActiveWorkbook`. However, What exactly is your XLA doing? If you can give me more insight to it then I can give you a direct answer i.e if I know it.

Comment: As said, the addin just provides a function to other spreadsheets. Hence I have no control when I am called. The function needs to infer the path of the ActiveWorkbooks folder, i.e., ActiveWorkbook.Path. It is actually this add-in: http://www.obba.info. I found a workaround to get that path - but it is quite "dirty". I am inspecting "Application.RecentFiles(1)".

Comment: But like I mentioned, once the workbook loads after you exit the `Protected Mode`, you can use `Activeworkbook`. To test whether the `Activeworkbook` is available to you or not, simply put the `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()` in the protected file. You will notice that the moment you exit the protected mode, you will get a `False`

Comment: Also updated the same in the above answer. See `Followup From Comments`

Comment: I understand that once the workbook has loaded that "ActiveWorkbook" is available. But my function was called before that! Execution order is "slave" to Excel updating the cells. At this point, ActiveWorkbook is invalid. Also: Which event should I register without adding code to the workbook which will be opened?

Comment: `But my function was called before that!` Can you please explain this part? I did ask you about this but seems like it went unnoticed...

Comment: Again: It is obvious that "ActiveWorkbook" is available at some later point in time. You can check this by running a macro, triggering the macro manually after the sheet has been "enabled". This is not the point. The point is that "ActiveWorkbook" is not available when Excel is calling the UDF's.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39149/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-christian-fries)

Comment: Thanks for the chat. I assume you found a good workaround (ActiveWindow.Parent)

Comment: I edited your answer and placed a summary with the most promising solution at the top. If you don't like it, re-edit it. Thanks again for the chat.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue today, and neither the accepted answer nor any other answer that I could find on this page or through searching the Google-verse worked for me. I'm using the version of Excel within Office 365, and I figured that was at the root of the problem.

I eventually came to a solution after finding a [Microsoft Excel 2010 resource](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2745652/object-model-calls-may-fail-from-workbookopen-event-when-exiting-prote) and hitting the old try-fail cycle for a few hours. Here's what I got:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents oApp As Application
Private bDeferredOpen As Boolean
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set oApp = Application
End Sub
Private Sub oApp_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If bDeferredOpen Then
        bDeferredOpen = False
        Call WorkbookOpenHandler(Wb)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub oApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Dim oProtectedViewWindow As ProtectedViewWindow
    On Error Resume Next
    'The below line will throw an error (Subscript out of range) if the workbook is not opened in protected view.
    Set oProtectedViewWindow = oApp.ProtectedViewWindows.Item(Wb.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Reset error handling
    If oProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing Then
        bDeferredOpen = False
        Call WorkbookOpenHandler(Wb)
    Else
        'Delay open actions till the workbook gets activated.
        bDeferredOpen = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub WorkbookOpenHandler(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    'The actual workbook open event handler code goes here...
End Sub
```

The difference between the 2010 solution and mine is that I had to call Workbook_Open and explicitly set the oApp variable there, because without that assignment neither the oApp_WorkbookActivate nor oApp_WorkbookOpen functions would fire when I opened the file.

Figured that someone else might be able to benefit from this, so I posted it, despite the fact that the most recent update to this thread is better than 2 years old.

Best.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Application.Caller.Parent.Parent instead of Application.Activeworkbook

Comment: I created a file containing 2 UDFs but I cannot duplicate your problem - what I am doing different?: you can download it from here https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=B4A055A3ADB4DC8C!282

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer to the original question, but a (dirty) workaround for a problem related to this.

I needed ActiveWorkbook to infer the workbooks path, that is ActiveWorkbook.Path.

An alternative to using ActiveWorkbook.Path is to check for `Application.RecentFiles(1).Path` which is the path of the most recently opened file. In many cases this will be the workbook for which the user just has "Enabled Editing". However, of course, this method may fail: In the case the used opened  another sheet, then enabling the previously opened sheet.

(Note: ActiveWorkbook.Path give the path of the folder, while Application.RecentFiles(1).Path gives the complete path of the file, so there has to be some post-processing).

Comment: I am not sure why do you want to take this workaround. See my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old thread, but i came across the same issue and i found solution ;)

The only way to go around it, is to use variable type *Workbook*

```
Dim wbk as Workbook
Set wbk = Application.ProtectedViewWindows(index).Workbook
```

**Warning:** 
*ActiveSheet* returns *Nothing* when active window is protected too.

```
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Set wsh = wbk.Worksheets(index)
```

Comment: Hi i am having this issue only in Excel 2016, Can you tell me what "index" is used for, do we define that?

Comment: @raphuket, yes, you have to pass a number (`index`), which corresponds with the order of workbooks in a collection or a name, which corresponds with the workbook name. Have a look at [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822367.aspx).

Comment: ahhh, That worked. with the link you gave me: here was the code that worked:
    Dim WbProtected As Workbook
    If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
    Set WbProtected = Application.ProtectedViewWindows(2).Workbook
    WbProtected.Sheet2.Activate
    Else:
    Sheet2.Activate
    End If

Comment: I'm glad i can help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it works.

```
If (UCase(ActiveWorkbook.Name) = ucase("<YOUR XLA NAME WITH EXTENSION>")) Then 
    End
End If
Set wbObj = ActiveWorkbook
```

First time when you run the macro, it just ends without doing anything. Second time it picks up the proper file.