# Excel VBA Object Variable or With block variable not set error, but only when downloaded from the internet

Tags: excel, vba

I am really struggling with this one and need some help here.
I have a software that customers required to download. Once downloaded, and after "Enable Editing" I must run some registration code. Anytime I reference a sheet or reference the workbook I get the "Object Variable or With block Variable Not set" bug. This wont happen on the same exact file if it was not downloaded from the internet and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Bug appears even on simple "Sheet6.Activate" or "ActiveWorkbook.name" code. Sheets are not hidden. I have even tried to declare public workbook variables. Any suggestions would GREATLY be appreciated. (Using Excel 2016 Windows, and this may not appear on earlier versions)

Code breaks at

> WkBkNm = ActWkBk.Name

```
Option Explicit
Dim ActWkBk As Workbook



Sub RegisterApp()
Set ActWkBk = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim Json, URL, LicKey, result, FullKey, WkBkNm As String
Dim LicCol As Long
'Set Computer ID
SetCompID
With Sheet1
'Parse Key
FullKey = .Range("A4").Value
LicKey = .Range("A12").Value 'Licence Key

'Check For License Type & Set Column
If InStr(FullKey, "LFBC") > 0 Then LicCol = 28
If InStr(FullKey, "LSBC") > 0 Then LicCol = 29
If InStr(FullKey, "LEBC") > 0 Then LicCol = 30
If InStr(FullKey, "LABC") > 0 Then LicCol = 31

'Check Registration
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "http://labor-burden-calculator.com/wp/?secret_key=56e9308d810df7.39344254&slm_action=slm_activate&license_key=" & LicKey & "&registered_domain=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34)
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
   objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
   'On Error GoTo NoConn
   objHTTP.send (Json)
   result = objHTTP.responseText
   'Check for issues
    If InStr(result, "maximum") > 0 Then GoTo RegUsed
    If InStr(result, "Invalid license key") > 0 Then GoTo RegUsed

   'Enter Results
   .Cells(3, LicCol).Value = LicKey
    .Cells(7, LicCol).Value = result 'Set Licence Result
    .Cells(6, LicCol).Value = .Range("A1").Value  'set Reg. Date
   'Some simple debugging
   Set objHTTP = Nothing
   .Calculate

   If InStr(result, "maximum") > 0 Then GoTo RegUsed
   If InStr(result, "Invalid license key") > 0 Then GoTo RegUsed
   'Check for proper registration:
   If .Range("A6").Value = "Not Reg" Or .Range("A10").Value = "False" Then
    MsgBox "Please re-enter your registration #, including the space and last 4 letters"
    .Range("A4").ClearContents
    Exit Sub
    Else:
        If Register.Visible = True Then Register.Hide 'Hide Registration Form
        If UpgradeFrm.Visible = True Then UpgradeFrm.Hide 'Hide Upgrade Form
        If UpgradeForceFrm.Visible = True Then UpgradeForceFrm.Hide 'Hide Upgrade Force Form
        If FreePopUp.Visible = True Then FreePopUp.Hide
   .Range("A4").ClearContents
   WkBkNm = ActWkBk.Name
   ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActWkBk.Path & "/Labor-Burden-Calculator_Registered.xlsm"
   Kill (ActWkBk.Path & "/" & WkBkNm)
    MsgBox "Thank you for Registering this product"
    StopCode
       StartNow
            'Show Empty Screen
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(6).Activate
        Sheet6.Shapes("WelcomeGrp").Visible = msoCTrue
        Sheet4.Range("B4").Value = True 'Keep From Employee Updating
        If LicCol = 28 Then MakeFree
        If LicCol = 29 Then MakeStandard
        If LicCol = 30 Then MakeEnterprise
        If LicCol = 31 Then MakeEnterprise

   End If
End With
Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Sheet4.Range("B4").Value = False
ResetCode
Exit Sub
NoConn:
MsgBox "To Register this product, pelase make sure you have a valid internet connection"
Exit Sub
RegUsed:
MsgBox "This Registration # has already been used. Please email support@Labor-Burden-Calculator.com to resolve this issue"
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok thanks i have updated the original post with the entire macro however the code breaks at the :
    WkBkNm = ActWkBk.Name
The "Save As" is just an attempt to figure out another way around the problem but it did not work. No need to save as but i am trying anything.

Comment: Uh, guessing you missed an `end if` somewhere. Too lazy to look through :/

Comment: It would be certainly possible and i am checking now however it would break every time on a missing End if, and not just when downloaded from the internet :(

Comment: I'm guessing that there's no `Application.ActiveWorkbook`, possibly because some security feature/setting is blocking it from opening.

Comment: Some type of block, correct, however this error appears only have I click the "Enable Editing" at the top of Excel (Which appears after you have downloaded an application from the internet)

Comment: Also this seems unque to 2016 and not getting the bug in 2010 Excel. Uhg.

Comment: Perhaps some useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345600/excels-vba-activeworkbook-is-nothing-when-enable-editing-from-protectedview