# Excel VBA 2016 Bug for ActiveSheet and ActiveWorkbook When Downloading from the Internet

Tags: vba, excel

I am wracking my brain trying to get around this bug with Excel 2016. The issue is simple:
Excel 2016 throws up an error for trying to reference the workbook (ActiveSheet or ActiveWorkbook) after it has been downloaded from the internet and after user has clicked Enable Editing.
This bug does not present itself in 2007 or 2010 Excel.
I have read a few threads, and tried many options suggested on this thread:[Excel's VBA ActiveWorkbook is "Nothing" when "Enable Editing" from ProtectedView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345600/excels-vba-activeworkbook-is-nothing-when-enable-editing-from-protectedview)

My sample workbook, which you can download I suggest, is empty except for the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub
```

I have tried

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate


Application.ActiveWorkbook
```

and a few others. This should be soo simple. All I want to do is activate a sheet. (Sure i can un-select the warning,  however this is a widely distributed application, and Excel defaults to this setting)

Here is my sample workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l94jxtvik656z17/Excel2016_BugTest.xlsm?dl=0

There is no bug on trying to open this before it has been downloaded.
I would greatly appreciate your help on this issue, as I have a lot of customer complaints on this.
Thanks,
Randy

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, seems to be working so far, here is what I found:

```
Dim WbProtected As Workbook
If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
Set WbProtected = Application.ProtectedViewWindows(1).Workbook
WbProtected.Sheet2.Activate
Else:
Sheet2.Activate
End If
```

Now seems to be working when I open without bugs.
Found the answer when someone replied on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24415286/1012838

and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822367.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: so it's a feature not a bug.

Comment: Well i call it a bug since it did not appear in 2007 or 2010 Excel. (if its a feature, its not one I appreciate)