# OnTime-event scheduling fails because of protected view

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

When opening an Excel-file from an untrusted origin, I get asked if I want to "Enable Editing":
[image]

However, when I do click that button, in Excel-files which contain `OnTime`-scheduling in the `Workbook_Open`-event, I get an error message and the macro aborts:

[image]
[image]

The code calling the macro is in the `ThisWorkbook`-object and looks like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Tempo
End Sub
```

While the macro itself is in a regular module, and looks like this:

Option Explicit

```
Public VARTIMER As Variant
Const TimeOut As Long = 30 'in minutes

Sub Salva()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Call Tempo
End Sub

Sub Tempo()
    VARTIMER = Format(Now + TimeSerial(0, TimeOut, 0), "hh:mm:ss")
    If VARTIMER = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(VARTIMER), "Salva"
End Sub
```

It all works perfectly fine as long as the file isn't opened in protected view, but when it is, I get the error shown above.

Can anyone tell me a way to avoid having the error shown appearing / aborting the code?

Marking all sites as trusted locations is not an option, because of company policies / a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

***Solution approach explanation:***

The problem relies that, in order to run the macros, the Excel instance needs the permission -which has not been granted yet- .Also, there may be a bug when it analyzes files that are checked out from a server (for example a SharePoint file). 

***Solution:***

Within the Workbook_Open event you may try something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
On Error Resume Next
If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = False And Application.ProtectedViewWindows.count < 0 Then Call Tempo
End Sub
```

More info could be consulted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345600/excels-vba-activeworkbook-is-nothing-when-enable-editing-from-protectedview) or [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/10/21/prevent-code-from-running-in-read-only).

**PS: Note that if the permission is not granted it won't be able to run the macro.